# Maven - Detect Multiple Versions of the Same Dependency in a project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a huge legacy project, which I want to clean. It has many modules, which have the same dependencies, but with different versions. Since the project is big, it's impractical to find this by myself.
Is there a way to detect the same dependency with different version in the project ?
e.g.

**module X:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**module Y:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `maven-enforcer-plugin`

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce</id>
      <configuration>
      <rules>
        <DependencyConvergence />
      </rules>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
      <goal>enforce</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html
https://www.ricston.com/blog/solving-dependency-conflicts-maven/

Comment: I like this one too

Comment: Does the enforcer plugin detect different versions in _different_ modules? I thought it only looks into the dependency:tree of each module.

Comment: @JFMeier if you run it from module A it doesn't check module B if A and B are siblings under one parent. But if you run from parent then if parent has A and B as dependencies then plugin should check them. If I understood your question correctly

Comment: @Ivan thanks. Currently I would like to handle my own dependencies only, not all the transient once.
I couldn't find a way to do it. Do you know if this is possible? i.e. control the depth of the convergence.

Comment: @Arik looks like it is impossible to limit depth

Comment: @Ivan The parent of multi-module project should _not_ have the modules as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven's `dependency:tree` (run it from the project's folder):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=junit
```

It will output all the `junit` dependencies of the project.

You can also call it without includes, and it will print every dependencies. Redirect it to a file, then you'll be able to use Notedpad++ or whatever to look for dependencies (also indirect ones) on a single page, with high signal and low noise:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose > dep.txt
```

Comment: No I can't. As I mentioned, there are many dependencies in the project. I don't know all of them.

Comment: You don't need to @Arik. Read the answer till the end :)

Comment: No I can't. I have hundreds of dependencies, all of them have dependencies.
The document you suggest will have hundreds of pages with high noise.
I suggest you try it - because I did it in the past.

Comment: Hundreds of *pages* of dependencies? Something must have been gone terribly wrong along the road. Good luck with that :|